# How to set header title before scrolling table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have created a table view and in its header I have set a title which will change at runtime depending on the previous view's table view click. Now initially while loading the table view header title is not updating with the latest selections, instead once I scroll down or up it updates immediately because I am setting the title in viewForHeaderInSection: method. Is it possible to update the header of section at the initial stage (i.e.. before scrolling.)

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer is reload tableview on appropriate callback method. For this problem I think `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` selector is a good point to override. You should add this method to your tableViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: You should reload the table view only when the datasource for it has finished whatever it was doing.

Comment: @ElJay That right. But Feroz Mohideen mentioned that in his question. The required data is assigned, not fetched from a remote source. _"I have set a title which will change at runtime depending on the previous view's table view click"_ In this case reloading data on `viewDidAppear:` selector is enough.

Answer (score -1):

Use the delegate/datasource method (you can use a public property that you set from the previous view controller):

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: when this method will be called, Its not getting called for me.

Comment: It gets called as long as you have wired up the delegate and datasource connections or set the parent view controller as the delegate for the tableview.  Also - whoever down-voted this answer, please explain why?  It's ridiculous to down-vote anything without an explanation.